# Why do I have to put async keyword to functions which have await keywords?

Tags: javascript, async-await, babeljs, ecmascript-next

I just want to wait for a process to finish, not want to make the function asynchronous.
See the below code.
I had to make getUserList asynchronous because there was an await keyword in the function. Therefore I also had to write like "await UsersService.getUserList" to execute the method and also I had to make the parent function asynchronous. That's not what I want to do.

```
import xr from 'xr' //a package for http requests

class UsersService {

  static async getUserList() {
    const res = await xr.get('http://localhost/api/users')
    return res.data
  }

}

export default UsersService
```

---

```
import UsersService from './UsersService'

class SomeClass {

  async someFunction() { //async again!!
    const users = await UsersService.getUserList() //await again!!
  }

}
```

Comment: Because without `async` the function is synchronous, hence - it's guaranteed to complete its body execution and return result.

Comment: "also I had to make the parent function asynchronous" --- you may use promises instead.

Comment: `//await again!!` --- sure, if it's asynchronous, you need to wait while it completes.

Comment: await means synchronous right? so the method getUserList should be synchronous for me.

Comment: I understand using promises can make the getUserList synchronous

Comment: "await means synchronous right? so the method getUserList should be synchronous for me" --- nope, it means "we are calling a function asynchronously and become asynchronous ourselves, since we need to wait for the result"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Is it a design choice?

Well this is because of the synchronous nature of JavaScript. If you wanted a function to run an asynchronous command synchronously, it would block up the entire program and this is highly undesirable, bad if it's client side, horrible if it's server-side. For this reason `async` functions exist. These functions are taken out of the normal flow which is why `await` works.

#### Why?

The other reason is that `await`+`async` are **syntax sugar** for promises. Promises **are asynchronous and you can't stop that**. What this means is that **await doesn't make an async function sync**, it just holds up the rest of the await function until it finishes. If it did block up the entire event loop, imagine if you wanted to create a app that would send data between clients. Your entire server app would hang everytime it made an async request rather than just make that single request asynchronous.

#### So think of it this way:

You are not making an async function sync, rather you are making the rest of the program async to cope with it.

So rather than think of `async` a requirement for `await`, think of them as a combination (`async`+`await`) as that's how they fundamentally work. If you'd like to learn more about async and await I highly recommend taking a read of my [blog article](http://web.archive.org/web/20160609080532/http://blog.vihan.org/index.php/2016/05/16/synchronously-async-ing/) which goes in depth on this.

Comment: "you are making the rest of the program async to cope with it." I finaly understand!!  thanks!!

Comment: Your blog is down.

Comment: Does that mean if I used async once, i have to make every function that uses this function async ?